# How to let a class public data member only be modified by class methods?

Tags: c++, class, constants

I have a class `cla` and a data member `x`. I can use `cla.x` to access its value and `cla.x=8` to change its value.
However, I want that `cla.x` only be accessed and can't be assigned. At the same time, I want `x` can be modified by a class method. Then how to do it?
If I set `x` to be `const`. It can't be assigned externally. However I can't change it in class either.
Code example:

```
class A{
public:
    int x=9;
    const int y;
}

A cla=A();
cout<<cla.x<<endl;    //I can access it.
cla.x=7;     //I can modified it.
cout<<cla.y<<endl;    //I can access a const int.
cla.y=8;    //Error.
```

If I set `x` to be a private member, I can change it use a class method and let a class method to return its value. But I can't use `cla.x` to access it.

Comment: Make it private and access via member functions.

Comment: Can’t be done. But what you can do is make `x` private, and have a public method `int getX()`.

Comment: If `y` is `const` you can only assign it a value to its statement or in `A` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that I can't do that.

I know that I can use a public method to return private value. But I just don't like the parenthesis of `cla.get_x()`.